# Eclipse SWT TreeCursor always has the text selected from the cell that was selected first time

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, selection

I tried using the same example from `TreeCursor` documentation:
http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/plain/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet360.java

On whichever cell I press enter (`SWT.CR`) for the first time, say I press on the cell 'root11', after this any cell that I click, 'root11' appears in it.
My requirement is to select the text from a cell to copy. I do not want to edit. So every time i click on a cell to copy its text, the text from the cell that was selected first time appears.

Any pointers on what could be causing this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `ENTER` is pressed on an item, the `widgetDefaultSelected` method is called. There, the `ControlEditor` sets a `Text` with the selected`TreeItem` text as its editor: `editor.setEditor(text);`.

This `Text` is then only disposed when `ENTER` or `ESC` is pressed on it, and in no other occasions. This means that the `Text` will still be visible with its original content even when you select another item.

To change this behavior you could modify the `widgetSelected` method to, for example, dispose the `Text` so it would be no longer visible or update its text with the current selected item.

To remove the `Text`:

```
@Override
public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

    // get the current editor
    Text text = (Text) editor.getEditor();

    if (text != null && !text.isDisposed()) {
        // remove the editor
        text.dispose();  
    }

    tree.setSelection(new TreeItem[] { cursor.getRow() });
}
```

To update the `Text` content:

```
@Override
public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

    // get the current editor
    Text text = (Text) editor.getEditor();

    if (text != null && !text.isDisposed()) {
        // update the text in the editor
        TreeItem row = cursor.getRow();
        int column = cursor.getColumn();
        text.setText(row.getText(column));
    }

    tree.setSelection(new TreeItem[] { cursor.getRow() });
}
```